scoped threads ignoring specified recv_timeout duration
I'm trying to timeout a scoped thread as per the reproducible below.
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::time::Duration;

trait Foo<T: Display + Clone> {
    fn fun(&self) -> T;
}

struct Bar<T: Display + Clone> {
    pub x: T,
}

impl<T: Display + Clone> Foo<T> for Bar<T> {
    fn fun(&self) -> T {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(100));
        self.x.clone()
    }
}

fn test(boxed: &Box<dyn Foo<usize> + Sync>) -> Option<usize> {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
    thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(move || {
            match sender.send(boxed.fun()) {
                Ok(_) => {},
                Err(_) => {},
            }
        });
    });
    
    let res = match receiver.recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(2)) {
        Ok(n) => Some(n),
        Err(_) => None,
    };
    
    return res;
}

pub fn main() {
    let boxed: Box<dyn Foo<usize> + Sync> = Box::new(Bar{x: 10});
    println!("{:?}", test(&boxed));
}

From my understanding, the thread should sleep for 100 seconds but after hanging for 2 seconds, should timeout. However the thread runs for the full 100 seconds instead and the timeout never occurs. I have to imagine this has something to do with using scoped threads as this was working without scoped threads before.
Why does the scoped thread not timeout after 2 seconds?
Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Scoped threads will always join all threads before returning, this is necessary for soundness. If you want some work to be done before the threads are joined, put it inside the call to thread::scope().

Even if you correct the code to run recv_timeout in parallel, you'll be stuck waiting for the thread to terminate before thread::scope can return. There isn't a way to kill the thread. If you want to be able to interrupt the thread then you have to arrange a way to do that. While async Rust has its own complexities, this is one problem that async solves very easily.

To terminate the scope, you should panic inside the scope. Move let res = match receiver.recv_timeout ... inside the scope just after s.spawn, you will receive an Err indicating the timeout error in the match. You can unwrap it or panic manually.

@Raeisi That won't solve anything. Even on panic, leaving the scope requires joining all spawned threads (not doing so would be unsound). Try it yourself and you will see that it still waits the full 100 seconds for the spawned thread to terminate before thread::scope returns.

Related: How can I quit/pause/unpause a timer thread?
